# c++ char* + std::vector memory leak

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, std

The following code is reading a big object collection (95G of compressed objects that are uncompressed via the WriteObject streamer) from disk and prints their content as strings.

object.cxx:

```
std::vector<char> ObjectHandler::GetObject(const std::string& path)
{
  TFile *file = new TFile(path.c_str());

  // If file was not found or empty
  if (file->IsZombie()) {
    cout << "The object was not found at " << path << endl;
  }

  // Get the AliCDBEntry from the root file
  AliCDBEntry *entry = (AliCDBEntry*)file->Get("AliCDBEntry");

  // Create an outcoming buffer
  TBufferFile *buffer = new TBufferFile(TBuffer::kWrite);

  // Stream and serialize the AliCDBEntry object to the buffer
  buffer->WriteObject((const TObject*)entry);

  // Obtain a pointer to the buffer
  char *pointer = buffer->Buffer();

  // Store the object to the referenced vector
  std::vector<char> vector(pointer, pointer + buffer->Length());

  // Release the open file
  delete file;

  delete buffer;

  return vector;
}
```

main.cxx:

```
ObjectHandler objHandler;
boost::filesystem::path dataPath("/tmp");
boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;

if (boost::filesystem::exists(dataPath) && boost::filesystem::is_directory(dataPath)) {
  for (static boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator directoryIterator(dataPath); directoryIterator != endIterator;
     ++directoryIterator) {
    if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(directoryIterator->status())) {

      cout << directoryIterator->path().string() << endl;
      std::vector<char> vector = objHandler.GetObject(directoryIterator->path().string());
      cout << vector << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

1) Is calling by value the correct way to implement this method? Am i doing additional copies that could be avoided if calling by reference?

2) This code is leaking and i am suspecting that either the *char *pointer* is to blame, or the actual *std::vector* that is returned by the *ObjectHandler::GetObject()* method. I've tested the implementation with the following code:

```
struct sysinfo sys_info;

sysinfo (&sys_info);

cout << "Total: " << sys_info.totalram *(unsigned long long)sys_info.mem_unit / 1024 << " Free: " << sys_info.freeram *(unsigned long long)sys_info.mem_unit/ 1024 << endl;
```

and the free ram is continuously reduced, until it reaches 0 and the program is killed.

Comment: If you feel that your program leaks memory, then you should try some debugging tool that helps to track that, such as [Massif](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif). Note that your program will run considerably slower using these tools.

Comment: `  // Get the AliCDBEntry from the root file
  AliCDBEntry *entry = (AliCDBEntry*)file->Get("AliCDBEntry");`?

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: off topic: Unless you have some unseen factor forcing dynamic allocation offile and buffer, don't dynamically allocate.

Answer (score 1):

"Memory Leak" is a term that can encompass a few things; depending on who you talk to.
One is a new without matching delete.
The other, often looked over, is memory that's still referenced and in scope, but just not used or needed.

If you don't use a profiller, then you can't be sure which you have, but since you've a large vector being passed around, and we don't know what you do with it, you could be doing the 2nd and no one would ever see.