# Is there a Valgrind for detecting "Memory Leaks" with Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

Our team has recently started to experiment with smart pointers, and I am increasingly concerned about our ability to detect and correct memory leaks.

I understand ( I think. . .) that in the purest sense, smart pointers rarely have true leaks, and if there are, it's generally related to circular references.  However, I am afraid this is masking the problem of a memory leak in the sense of being "unwanted and unnecessary memory consumption".

For example, when using traditional raw pointers, if an object fails to properly clean up memory, we could run Valgrind and at the end of the program, anything left was a leak (often this could be a leak that continues to grow during program execution leading to severe problems). . . Now with smart pointers, these all get cleaned up before program exit and Valgrind won't see any lost references to allocated memory.

In general I see the value of smart pointers in helping developers prevent leaks, however we are human and make mistakes, thats why we have debugging tools!

How can we detect unwanted memory growth due to a programming error, like we used to be able to do with Valgrind and raw pointers?

... Edits

1)
Foolishly I normally associate Valgrind with Memcheck and that is how I intended to use it above.  My apologies for confusion.

2) As an illustration here is an example:

Consider  multi-threaded application to process data.  The first thread reads input (from disk or network whatever), then passes a data block to another thread running Algorithm Step 1 via a queue,  Step1's thread grabs data out of its input queue does its thing and passes the data on to Step2.  Repeat until a final thread writes out a result (to disk or network).  When all the input data is processed, each thread kills itself after it finishes the last items and the program exits.

Now during execution our footprint grows significantly, assuming we can process data as fast as we ingest it, there must be a leak.  Using raw pointers I used to detect this kind of error with Memcheck which would have reported lost or possibly lost blocks of memory at the program end which we could track down and fix.

3) In our haste to learn and apply smart-pointers we probably used "shared_ptr" where as another type may have been more appropriate for our application.

Comment: I fail to see why valgrind will not work.  If you have a leak that means a resource will not be cleaned up automatically and should be able to be detected.

Comment: Because when the smart pointer loses scope it destroys itself automatically.  This can occur when the object that created it loses scope.  If an object lasts the entire runtime (like one representing a thread and its input/output queues of data to process) and there is growth in memory consumption due to an error, the smart pointers are still destroyed at program exit and valgrind won't notice the loss.

Comment: I'm not sure that could happen with the way the smart pointer API is setup.  If you had an example of something that would be nice to see.

Comment: Good tools don't replace good craftsmanship. You still have to write sane code, and that means minimal ownership (always unique, never shared, unless you know better), tight scopes, and code review. Smart pointers *allow* you to write good code; they don't magically cause arbitrary code to be good.

Comment: Writing good code is always the goal, but mistakes happen, thats why we have tools to help us find our mistakes!

Comment: @Toymakerii _"thats why we have tools to help us find our mistakes! "_ Some static analysis tools are awesome doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's significant memory growth, you'll see that directly or using valgrind's massif tool.

It's also worth noting that there are many types of smart pointer.
You mention circular references, so presumably you're talking about `shared_ptr`? That's the only case where circular references are a risk - it's not general to all smart pointers.

In general, in order of preference:

1. avoid (direct) dynamic allocation - use containers or other dedicated types to manage memory
2. avoid complex ownership and/or lifetimes of dynamically-allocated resources: `unique_ptr` is easy to reason about
3. if you *must* share ownership, that implies your object lifetime is inherently non-deterministic, and thus hard to reason about. However, you can't leak a "shared" object without leaking its owners, so a leak implies some confusion higher up your program structure

   - note that if you have references that shouldn't keep a shared object alive, you should use `weak_ptr` instead. This also serves to break statically-predictable cycles

Comment: I noted the circular reference for clarity and distinction of the type of memory leak I am looking for.  It sounds like Massif might be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

As per my answer in [c++ char* + std::vector memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961690/c-char-stdvector-memory-leak/39961979#39961979)

There are many definitions of memory leak - and valgrind will not detect things that are still in scope.  That's the job of the engineer and debugger.  (How can any software guess when you might decide you want to use something that's still in scope?)

Comment: This is precisely the problem we used to be able to solve with memcheck.  Based on your linked answer, perhaps we should start using Massif to profile the heap and manually detect unwanted growth?

Comment: That will detect it - but if you already know that you've got this problem, you won't see anything new.  Take a look around for singletons, and global variables, they're a good starting point

Comment: Looks like Massif provides some level of tracking where the allocations occur, which should be equivalent to memcheck's "track-origins" we will give this a shot!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to be aware of with smart pointers is that circular dependencies between classes holding e.g. a `std::shared_ptr<>` of each other won't be cleaned up properly.

I'm afraid that's a situation not detected with valgrind.

Though such can be resolved using `std::weak_ptr<>`.

Comment: This is why weak references exist :)

Comment: @UKMonkey Sure. That's a way to resolve that kind of problems.